# Markov switching model estimation

Tags: models, calibration, hidden-markov-model

We are testing Markov switching models to forecast risk regimes, similar to the paper by [Kritzman, Page and Turkington](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2066848). We find that in some cases the [Baum-Welch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baum%E2%80%93Welch_algorithm) algorithm converges very slowly or not at all. Apparently this issue is known for hidden Markov models in speech recognition and other fields, where several alternatives to Baum-Welch have been proposed: for example, [Bayesian estimation](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/D/D07/D07-1031.pdf) by M. Johnson or estimators based on an [entropic prior](http://www.merl.com/publications/docs/TR98-19.pdf) by M. Brand.

Have these alternatives been applied to financial times series? Is there a reason to favor one particular approach, apart from slow convergence?